# Networkx graph is not planar

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to draw a network graph. My code is very simple. For small case studies, this code works well. But for a larger sample with more vertices and arcs, I get G is not planar error. What is the reason for this error?

> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\layout.py in
> planar_layout(G, scale, center, dim)
> 945         is_planar, embedding = nx.check_planarity(G)
> 946         if not is_planar:
> --> 947             raise nx.NetworkXException("G is not planar.")
> 948     pos = nx.combinatorial_embedding_to_pos(embedding)
> 949     node_list = list(embedding)

NetworkXException: G is not planar.

```
def createAttackGraphNonPlanar(pos):
    G=nx.DiGraph(directed=True)
    G.add_nodes_from([nodes_map[n] for n in nodes])
    print(G.nodes())
    
    
    G.add_edges_from([  (nodes_map[e[0]],nodes_map[e[1]]) for e in arcs])
 
    nx.draw_planar(G, pos=pos, node_size=30, node_color='red', with_labels = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function draw_planar is for drawing a [planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) from the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_planar.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_planar),

> Draw a planar networkx graph with planar layout.

Not all graphs are planar graphs.

To draw any graph use [draw](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw) instead, for example (for demo only):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.dodecahedral_graph()
nx.draw(G)  # networkx draw()
plt.draw()  # pyplot draw()
```

For more information on drawing graphs, see this [link](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/drawing.html)

Comment: Thanks @Dani Mesejo